# Как сделать, чтобы Drawable не масштабировалось в соответствии с dpi?

Tags: android

У меня проблема с проектированием интерфейса программы под Android

Фоновое изображение кнопки с закругленными краями задается 9 файлами (left, right,up,down, left-up, left-down, right-up, right-down, medium) - 4 границы, 4 угла и 1 центр.

И описывается Drawable с названием background_button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:top="12dp" android:right="12dp" android:left="12dp" android:bottom="12dp">
        <bitmap
               android:antialias="true"
               android:dither="false"
               android:filter="false"
               android:src="@drawable/bg_bt_m"
               android:gravity="fill_vertical|fill_horizontal"

               />
    </item>
        <item android:left="12dp" android:right="12dp">
                <bitmap
                       android:antialias="true"
                       android:dither="false"
                       android:filter="false"
                       android:src="@drawable/bg_bt_u"
                       android:gravity="top|fill_horizontal"

                       />
            </item>
    <item  android:left="12dp" android:right="12dp">
        <bitmap
               android:antialias="true"
               android:dither="false"
               android:filter="false"
               android:src="@drawable/bg_bt_d"
               android:gravity="bottom|fill_horizontal" />
    </item>
    <item android:top="12dp" android:bottom="12dp">
        <bitmap
               android:antialias="true"
               android:dither="false"
               android:filter="false"
               android:src="@drawable/bg_bt_l"
               android:gravity="left|fill_vertical" />
    </item>
    <item android:top="12dp" android:bottom="12dp">
        <bitmap
               android:antialias="true"
               android:dither="false"
               android:filter="false"
               android:src="@drawable/bg_bt_r"
               android:gravity="right|fill_vertical" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/bg_bt_ld"
               android:antialias="true"
               android:dither="false"
               android:filter="false"
               android:gravity="left|bottom" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap
               android:antialias="true"
               android:dither="false"
               android:filter="false"
               android:tileMode="disabled"
               android:src="@drawable/bg_bt_lu"
               android:gravity="left|top" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap
               android:antialias="true"
               android:dither="false"
               android:filter="false"
               android:src="@drawable/bg_bt_rd"
               android:gravity="right|bottom" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap
               android:antialias="true"
               android:dither="false"
               android:filter="false"
               android:src="@drawable/bg_bt_ru"
               android:gravity="right|top" />
    </item>
        </layer-list>
```

P.S. Я заметил, что при задании смещения android:left, android:right,android:top,android:bottom в пикселях, изображения накладываются друг на друга, а при задании в dp, все стыкуется.

Сама кнопка задается следующим образом

```
<Button android:layout_width="218dp" android:layout_height="50dp" android:text="ВОЙТИ"
                   android:id="@+id/bEnter" android:background="@drawable/background_button"
                   />
```

В итоге на экране устройства фон кнопки получается размытый, когда я проверил закругления на скриншоте с устройства с исходным изображением закруглений, то на скриншоте получаются в 1.5 раз больше. Скорее всего это может быть связанно с тем, что размер изображения изменяется в соответствии с dpi, Но как сделать, чтобы изображение не было привязано к dpi? Или проблема в чем-то другом?

Answer (score 1):

> Фоновое изображение кнопки с закругленными краями задается 9 файлами (left, right,up,down, left-up, left-down, right-up, right-down, medium) - 4 границы, 4 угла и 1 центр.

Я возможно что-то не понимаю, но... зачем? К чему все эти шаманства и сложности? Nine-patch же есть.

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понял чего вам хочется, но если хотите чтобы изображение показывалось без масштабирования надо положить его в каталог `drawable-nodpi`:

> Resources for all densities. These are
> density-independent resources. The
> system does not scale resources tagged
> with this qualifier, regardless of the
> current screen's density.